# Distort image to display on leaflet.js based on known 16x16 point grid

Tags: leaflet, coordinate-system, php

I have an image that is a satellite picture, and with php gd I want to distort it so I can overlay it on a leaflet.js map. To make it a bit more simple, I have a grid of points, 16x16 which bind the image to the coordinates, like I chopped the image to 256 pieces and found appropriate coordinates for corners of each of those pieces.

It's tedious and inefficient to draw 256 pieces simultaneously, hence I'd like to process the image on the server-side. Is it even possible to do it with just PHP's GD library or is it necessary to reinforce the arsenal? The projection I'm using (and would like to stick with) is standard leaflet.js EPSG:3857. How do I even start about such a task ?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to georeference (that's the term) image with QGIS. See my answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/111411/30197) for tutorial links.

Comment: I guess I'll have to learn more about QGIS then, I'll try that and approve Your answer when I succeed, allright ? Oh, and thanks by the way :)

Comment: OK, from what I gather QGIS is a standalone software, used by a human. What I need to do is to build a script that will do georeferencing on the server-side on its own, based on known data, on the fly.